# Заполнение таблицы случайными значениями на основе другой таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть три таблицы, все поля заполнены, кроме developers.project_id.

**Вопрос:** как заполнить поле случайным образом на основе имеющихся связей?

То есть назначить каждому разработчику случайный проект его компании.

[image]

Comment: Приведите в текстовом виде скрипты создания этих таблиц и заполнения их тестовыми данными. на вскидку `update Tab1 set xx_id=(select id from tab2 where tab2.company=tab1.company order by rand() limit 1` но это не совсем постгресовский синтаксис. надо пробовать на тестовой базе что бы сделать постгресовский вариант, но основная идея думаю останется той же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно с повторами, то пойдёт и такое:

```
UPDATE developers SET project_id = (
  SELECT id FROM projects WHERE developers.id = developers.id
  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
);
```

`WHERE developers.id = developers.id` нужен, чтобы `RANDOM()` генерировал случайное значение для каждого запроса. См. http://www.simononsoftware.com/problem-with-random-in-postgresql-subselect/.

Если нужно, чтобы project_id был уникальным, лучшее, что смог придумать - это вот такая конструкция:

```
WITH d(id, r) AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM developers
), p(id, r) AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RANDOM()) FROM projects
), d2p(d_id, p_id) AS (
  SELECT d.id, p.id FROM d JOIN p ON d.r = p.r
) UPDATE developers SET project_id = (
  SELECT p_id FROM d2p WHERE d_id = id
);
```